# Preventing layer name from snap tip blocking view in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: snapping, arcgis-pro

[image: enter image These are the ONLY SNAPPING OPTION I SEEdescription here]

[image]

When I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.2 and I get near a layer, the layer name physically pops up and it blocks my ability to see where the pointer is in relation to the line and its intersection with another line to snap.

I cannot see where I can turn this snap tip of a layer name off.

Comment: If you're using ArcGIS Pro, you must have a subscription which would entitle you to support from your local ESRI distributor. I'd shoot them an email to see if there's a known workaround, otherwise you may be able to raise this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Snap Tips, while leaving Snapping On, does not seem to be possible in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 (which I am currently using) or earlier versions because these are the only Snapping Options available:

[image]

In comparison, ArcMap 10.5 has these Snapping Options that would help you, if you were using the older architecture:

[image]

Unless turning off Snapping in ArcGIS Pro is an option for you, it looks like seeing Snap Tips is unavoidable.

To have this changed I would recommend that you submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).

---

I have upvoted [your ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12976-wish-to-be-able-to-turn-off-snap-tips-in-arcgis-pro-12) but so far only three people have expressed an interest in it.